# Two questions regarding one-counter automata

Tags: automata, formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar, finite-automata

Let's assume we have a non-deterministic one-counter automaton without epsilon transitions. I have two questions:

1. Is there an algorithm (if yes, what is it?) that answers whether this automaton accepts $\Sigma^*$ where $\Sigma$ is the alphabet of the automaton?
2. Let's assume that both $L$ and $\Sigma^* \setminus L$ are recognized by certain such automata. Does it mean that $L$ is regular? Why/why not?

Comment: Your first question is answered in *Restricted one-counter machines with undecidable universe problems*, Ibarra, O.H. Math. Systems Theory (1979) 13: 181. doi:10.1007/BF01744294.

Answer (score 1):

Since a comment seems to have answered part 1 of your question, I'll tackle part 2.

Consider the language $L = \{ a^n b^n \}$. It's almost trivial to construct a one counter automaton to recognize this language; to accept $\Sigma^* - L$, switch all accepting states in the machine that accepts $L$ to rejecting, and all rejecting to accepting. This language is the classic example though of a language which cannot be recognized by a finite automata, and therefore not regular (see: pumping lemma).

Comment: I forgot to mention that my automata accepts by final state alone (also, just to be clear, counter cannot go below zero).

Comment: The restriction of accepting by final state only changes the implementation of the machine, the power remains the same. $L$ can be recognized by a one-counter machine, and not by a finite state automata.

Comment: Could you give me an example of automaton recognizing such langauge? Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but I can't really work it out.